# How can I start an application with a preset window position using the command line?

Tags: gnome, window-manager

I have gnome-terminal configured as a Startup Application in 18.04.  I would also like it to start snapped to the right of the screen.  I was able to do this using something Compiz in 16.04.  Maybe using some geometry math?

Answer (score 2):

***workaround***

for the first time snap the gnome-terminal to the right and run below commands to get the required values..

1. `tput cols`
2. `tput lines`

Example:

```
pratap@i7:~$ tput cols
70
pratap@i7:~$ tput lines
38
pratap@i7:~$
```

3. `xdotool getactivewindow getwindowgeometry`

(install the package `xdotool` if not yet installed.. with the command `sudo apt install xdotool`)

Example:

```
pratap@i7:~$ xdotool getactivewindow getwindowgeometry
Window 54525958
  Position: 726,91 (screen: 0)
  Geometry: 650x713
pratap@i7:~$
```

4. `gnome-terminal --geometry=70x38+726+91` add this command to your startup applications

[image]

Please note that due to pixels and character input there will be little variation between this geometry and real snap right..

Comment: This answer was somewhat working in Ubuntu 20.10 but not in 21.04.