# Launch terminal with initial position as split right?

Tags: gnome-terminal, configuration, .desktop

I know that it is possible to edit the desktop entry for gnome-terminal and set geometry arguments, but I am wondering if it is possible to have gnome terminal by default launch with the positioning that results from entering the `Super + Right` keyboard shortcut.

Comment: something like this https://askubuntu.com/q/1169195/739431?

Comment: My hope is to be able to launch terminal and then split left whatever i'm working on, but just positioning won't respect the split left right boundary/bond when resizing as it's not an actual split. My hope is to maybe alias launching a terminal to launch terminal and then issue a command to gnome to split right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***WorkAround***

Install the package `xdotool` if not yet installed with the command `sudo apt install xdotool`

Write a script with below content in your `$HOME/bin/` with the name something called `GT.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

gnome-terminal && xdotool sleep 0.1 key super+Right
```

Create a desktop entry with the name something called `GT.desktop` in `/usr/share/applications/` with below content

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=GT
Exec=/bin/bash /home/<user>/bin/GT.sh
```

This way when you open All apps.. you have to select `GT` icon instead of Terminal icon

[image]

Disable the Default Shortcut for "Launch Terminal" and then Create a Custom shortcut with Ctrl+Alt+T for the command `/bin/bash home/<user>/bin/GT.sh`

---

Observed that the shortcut Ctrl+Alt+T Opens new terminal windows as expected. But clicking on the desktop entry icon "GT" is not opening as expected if a terminal is already opened..